# What will be the value of $ 2\cos^{2}\theta - 1 $ , if $ \cos^{4}\theta - \sin^{4}\theta = \frac{2}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

The question was **What will be the value of $ 2\cos^{2}\theta - 1 $**, if $ \cos^{4}\theta - \sin^{4}\theta = \frac{2}{3}$

Here is my working:

$\cos^{4}\theta - \sin^{4}\theta = \frac{2}{3} $

$(\cos^{2}\theta)^{2}-(\sin^{2}\theta)^{2} = \frac{2}{3}$

$(\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta)\cdot(\cos^{2}\theta+\sin^{2}\theta) = \frac{2}{3}$

$\cos2\theta = \frac{2}{3}$

But I am stuck at this step so can anyone help me ?

Comment: $cos2x = 2cos^2x-1$

Comment: thanks @insipidintegrator I was not aware of this identity , I am currently a high school  student ust moved in 11th so just facing these sort of questions  . Thanks Once again

Comment: That is one of the 3 standard formulas for double-angle cosine...

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote.

Comment: I also @algevristis they think if they know the answer it's obvious that everyone will know

Comment: A shortcut is to recognize that $\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1 = (2/3).$  This represents a shortcut because it dovetails with your intermediate evaluation of $\cos^4(\theta) - \sin^4(\theta).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got  the answer

$\cos2\theta = 2\cos^{2}\theta - 1$

$2\cos^{2}\theta - 1 = \frac{2}{3} $

This is our required answer